# Going from a 1x8 to 2x10 setup

Tags: chainring, drivetrain, hybrid-bike

After using my bike for a year I feel that although I enjoy the simplicity of a single chainring setup, I would prefer a more versatile 2x10 setup and would like to move to it. Currently the two cranksets I am looking at buying are the SRAM Apex White 50-34t & the Shimano 105 5700 52-39t.

What else apart from one of these, a new set of shifters and front derailleur would I need to buy as well, should I also replace the rear cassette & derailleur?

Comment: You may want to examine your frame to ensure it has braze-ons to accomodate the cabling for the front derailleur/shifter.

Comment: Going to 2*8 would be a lot cheaper for only slightly less gain. Saves the requirement for new derailleur, rear shifter/brifter (which is it) and maybe chain.

Comment: @mattnz okay i might do that instead. My only thing is that im not a fan of the current SRAM setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go from a 1x8 to 2x10 drive train you will need:

1. Replacement shifters for 2x10 drive trains
2. Front derailleur for double 10 speed crankset
3. Double 10 speed crankset
4. 10 speed chain
5. 10 speed cassette
6. 10 speed rear derailleur
7. Cable outers for front derailleur

Comment: all of which would cost a tidy sum. I know the Shimano kit can be bought as a groupset which might be cheaper than the individual parts.

Comment: also since you will replace the brake/shifter (brifter) you should take into account the amount of pull available! some brakes will not correctly work with some brake levers or they will be less effecient.